# Cant apply column on row with flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, row, multiple-columns

I want to achieve something like a row with columns inside and the content of those columns should be vertically placed.

Like this:

[image]

Im using react so I have various components.
What I think thats right but keeps the "a" and "b" in the same row is:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

container class:

```
const Field2 = (props) => {

    return (

        <div className={"container"}>
            {props.texturasEscolhidas.map(a => {

                return (
                        <Field2Content>
                            {a.labelNormalize}
                            {a.name}
                        </Field2Content>
                )
            })}
        </div>

    )
};

export default Field2;
```

content class:

```
const Field2Content = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className={"content "}>
                {props.children}
        </div>
    )
};

export default Field2Content;
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML?

Comment: @Goediaz updated my question. Its react, not quite HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost right. I've made an example below and documented in the code. Hope this helps.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: lightblue; /* for visibility */
  justify-content: space-around; /* spreads flex items horizontally */
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightgreen; /* for visibility */
  width: 10%;
  align-items: center; /* places paragraphs in the center horizontally */
  margin: 2em 0; /* for top and bottom */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this: Make a wrapper with items and `display` it with `flexbox` in a `row` and use `space-around` to get your design. Within the items you can put children (i took simply a span with a text) and `display` them in a `column` also with `flexbox`. Use `align-items: center;` to get your position.

Heres a helpful link about `flexbox`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Below the working snippet, hope this helps:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</spa>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 3px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
     <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```